# Meaning of 'to break down the barriers'

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

From the [article](http://www.english-test.net/lessons/53/index.html):

> It still remained a mystery why it had happened.
>   There was a wall of secrecy surrounding the whole affair which it was
>   virtually impossible to break through. One reporter on the local paper
>   however was determined to ***break down*** the barriers and get to the
>   bottom of the matter.

I'm a little confused by the meaning of break down here. I'd say that it has something to do with starting communicating with people involved in the affair and put out some details about it.

Comment: wall of secrecy->barriers.  break down the barriers....

Comment: @TRomano ??? What do you mean? How can we break down wall of __secrecy__???

Comment: I think he told you  that *break down* here means *to ruin* a wall of secrecy (wall is used figuratively here).

Comment: ["**Tear down this wall!**" is a line from a speech made by US President Ronald Reagan in West Berlin on June 12, 1987, calling for the leader of the Soviet Union, Mikhail Gorbachev, to open up the barrier which had divided West and East Berlin since 1961](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tear_down_this_wall!) Barriers and walls are ***tall*** things preventing passage/communication, so it's natural to associate ***down*** with verbs getting rid of them, just as we *put **up** barriers* when creating them in the first place.

Comment: ...but I don't think the cited usage *is* a "phrasal verb" - it's just an ordinary preposition use, with a literal meaning not significantly changed by omitting ***down***. It's a phrasal verb in, say, *break down a car repair bill* (itemize the costs of the different charges making up the total bill).

Comment: Yes, see [break something⟷down, 2nd meaning](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/break-down?q=break+down).

Comment: @Dmitrii Bundin:  Your question, *How can we break down a wall of **secrecy**?*, has nothing to do with the English language per se, but with figurative language in general. You obviously understand what **break down** means.

Comment: .This could also mean that local reporter in consideration was determined to undertake any problems or difficulties to go to depth of the matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if *break down* is really being used phrasally here ...

You can add a preposition after a verb to indicate the direction that the activity was pointed toward.  This can overlap with phrasal verbs.

> I threw down the ball to Jimmy = I threw the ball in a downward direction to Jimmy, Jimmy is below me.

And sometimes the direction of the activity is specified but the subject of the activity is not directly "aiming" the action:

> We broke down the wall = We destroyed the wall.  We didn't necessary apply force in a downward motion but when a wall breaks it will fall down to the ground by itself.

But *break down* can be used to describe destruction for things other than walls:

> Relations between the US and North Korea broke down.

It also can be used to not necessarily mean "to be destroyed" but something like "remove".  So barriers in the sense of things that block communication are a logical type of wall and to "break them down" means to find a way through the barrier.

It also can mean *to take apart in preparation to be put away*:

> The carnival ended, the workers broke down the tent and later loaded it on a truck.

A meaning of *break down* that is not related to the above, where it 100% *is* a phrasal verb, means to *reduce to smaller parts, typically to try to understand.*

> This is a complicated topic, let's break it down into simpler concepts so we can understand.

Answer (score 2):

> Here is the definition of break down; Suddenly cease to function.

So when a wall gets destroyed or falls down it, *suddenly ceases to function.*

> But in this case they are talking about a figurative "wall"

*One reporter* on the local paper however was determined to break down the barriers and get to the bottom of the matter.

So that reporter was trying to break down this figurative *wall of secrecy* so that whatever the "wall" was *hiding or protecting* would be exposed.

Also understand a walls function is to **hide or protect** something,
So when it ceases to function that "wall stops **hiding and protecting** therefore exposing what the reporter is trying to expose by breaking down the wall.